# Macbook Pro 2011(early) BCM4331 Wifi not working on kernel 4.4.0-108 and 4.4.0-109

Tags: wireless, macbook-pro

My wifi broke on the new kernels ... I'm running xubuntu on a macbook pro 2011(early).  Ever since we got new version of the kernel higher than 4.4.0-104, I can't get wifi to work anymore ... Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

I booted into the working 4.4.0-104 kernel and reinstalled bcmwl-kernel-source and dkms. That reinstalled the wl.ko module for all kernels, since the wl.ko module was missing from the newer kernels and was not loaded at boot.

`sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source dkms --purge`

`sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source dkms`

Comment: works with the 18.04 live cd too

Comment: It is 2023 and this trick still works on Ubuntu 22.04.2 on a mac mini late 2012.  Cheers.